Interpreting the output of badblocks: when is it time to replace the MicroSD card?
Context
I am running a Raspberry Pi Zero with a Micro SD as it is designed. 
However, for this specific application,
I cannot use a read-only system as I usually do with a Raspberry Pi.
Objective
Keep an eye on the health state of the Micro SD (and eventually get a notification somehow that it is time to replace the Micro SD).
Questions

What is the best way to monitor the health state of the Micro SD (no fsck as I cannot unmount the Micro SD while the system is running)?
Is the following proposed approach the best solution in terms of practicality and effectiveness?

Proposed approach
I thought of using the output of badblocks to keep an eye on the state
of the Micro SD, and eventually replacing it when it is time. 
But when is it time to replace the Micro SD? 
How many bad blocks are too many? 
Should I look at write or read errors, or both?
I made the following consideration: Micro SD cards automagically reallocate data outside of bad blocks. So if the Micro SD is 80% full, there are 20% of blocks that can "go bad" and still keep the Micro SD running. Adding a little bit of a confidence interval, can we say that if badblocks outputs a number of bad blocks that is below, let's say, 50% of the free-space blocks, it is still safe to use the SD card?
To clarify:

Total number of blocks: 100
Free space (in blocks): 20
Maximum number of blocks that are acceptable to be corrupted (or whatever): 10


SD cards are inherently unreliable. Make sure you have a recovery strategy if the card goes bad before your monitoring catches it.


How many bad blocks are too many?

A single one.
badblocks is the wrong tool. The moment it reports the first bad block, the flash medium has been already used to the point of damage. Just like fsck, it can only detect when things have already gone wrong – and you might have lost data.
In SD cards (and generally, all flash mass storage devices you're likely to encounter), there's a flash translation layer in the hardware, which makes the inherently analog, unreliable, and wearout-prone actual memory look like plain, reliable, block-addressable memory. It does that by two means:

extensive forward error correction to combat the fact that bits simply like to flip in the physical medium; the more a page has been written to, the more often this happens
wear leveling, to make writes to logical pages (as seen by the Pi / operating system) end up as distributed as possible over the physical pages, so that you don't end up hammering the same page all the time

That means the wear leveling happens in the hardware, invisible to the operating system. The moment the file system driver sees a bad block, there were irreparable errors that the error correction couldn't handle. That's very unlikely, unless that page had been written to a lot, in which case, the overall write volume already brought the wear leveling to its knees. Meaning that you've written so many times so that even after distributing the writes all over the medium, some places were written to so often that they failed. (The next thing that usually happens is that the controller inside the SD card tells the host that it has become a read-only device).
So, nope. You can't check the state of the SD card by verifying the data on it (which is what both fsck and badblocks do), unless you wait until it's far too late.
You need info from inside the SD card with an estimate of how much total write "reserve" there is. There is, as far as I know, no standard reply for the "gimme health information, dear SD card" command, but "industrial" labeled SD cards might support CMD65 and there's a few linux tools (sdmon) that support reading it.
In short: if you need reliable write storage, then SD cards aren't it. The interface wasn't designed for that originally; instead, it was assumed writes would happen mostly linearly, in large chunks at once, and with very little duplicate writing (typical for camera usage: write one full image, then update the FAT a single time).
If you need long-term reliable mass storage on your Pi, I'm afraid your best choice is buying an USB-to-M.2 (SATA, typically) converter enclosure (and a powered USB hub, if necessary),  and plugging it into your Rpi zero, after equipping it with an SSD. Most of these controllers support S.M.A.R.T. commands, so that you actually get something to monitor, using smartctl; make sure that each attribute's "Normalized" value is above the "Threshold" value. Make sure you don't buy the cheapest SSD you can find, but every mid-range SSD brings attribe 177, wear-level-count, attribute 195 Hardware ECC Recovered and attribute 182 erase-fail-count-total. A decrease in normalized values of these doesn't necessarily mean anything bad (it's expected to happen, otherwise these metrics would be useless), but as soon as you're getting closer to the threshold, you might want to consider replacing the SSD. (Note that chances are your Rpi Zero might die first; between the 5€ RPi Zero and a consumer SSD, the SSD is the one that was designed for mechanical, thermal and electrical reliability).

Thank you for the exhaustive explanation. But if only one bad block is too many, should I replace the microsd as soon as there is one bad block? More bad blocks are indicative of a failure about to happen?

I was thinking the same thing... the instant an error is detectable by the OS, replace it immediately - It Has Failed There are a lot of things going on behind the curtain dealing with errors; when it reaches a point you can see them, it is beyond done. (for the record, spinning drives have the same mechanisms. would you continue to use an IDE drive that has reported even a single bad block to the OS?)

@giovi321 no, "More bad blocks are indicative of a failure about to happen" is wrong: The moment you see the first bad block, the failure has already happened. It's too late, then.

What if the bad block can be “fixed” by fsck? Is it a bad block or not? Many thanks once again

@giovi321 how many times should I repeat what I've written above and in my answer?

I understood SD cards lock themselves into read-only mode when one block is bad (or even worse a lockdown or factory mode, to use recovery software). That is, since one bad block exposed to the OS means it was fully unable to recover, and it's already "worn out", better to replace the SD card fully (not like SSD where the controller does extra things).  Regarding the SMART protocol on SD cards, there is some info here: https://groups.google.com/g/beagleboard/c/u8J6Jl9o1Mw
